# delete operator for instances holding other instances

Tags: c++

I have a question regarding delete operator. In case there are 3 instances each holding the next/previous instance how to delete it?

```
class A : public Parent
{
privte:
  A* next;
  A* previous;
public:
  void setNext(A*);
  void setPrevious(A*);
};

.. 
int main()
{
  A* obj1 = new A();
  A* obj2 = new A(); 
  A* obj3 = new A();

  obj1->setNext(obj2);
  obj2->setNext(obj3);
  obj3->setNext(nullptr);

  obj1->setPrevious(nullptr);
  obj2->setPrevious(obj1);
  obj3->setPrevious(obj2);

  return 0;
}
```

if I delete obj1.. obj2 and obj3 get deleted auotmatically. Why? Is this a memory leak? Are they actually deleted? I don't understand such behaviour. Shouldn't there be a delete for every new?

Comment: They don't get deleted automatically (at least, not so far as this code shows).

Comment: delete obj3; delete obj2; delete obj1, or any other combination unless you don't use bad pointers

Comment: Class A doesn't even have a destructor. Does its Parent class have one?

Comment: class A has constructor

Comment: After I delete obj1, when i try to delete obj2 i run into an unhanded exception error. When I debug, I see that obj2 and all its variables are NULL.

Comment: please paste the code of methods

Comment: @TacyNathan You probably shouldn't call `delete next; delete previous;` from your destructor code :P ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to think of resource ownership issues. You have make some policy decisions. Then write code that confirms to that policy.

After you execute:

```
obj1->setNext(obj2);
```

who owns `obj2`? Is `obj2` owned by `obj1`? Is it owned by the calling function or a higher level object?

If your policy says that `obj1` owns `obj2`, then, you have to delete `obj2` when you delete `obj1`.

If your policy says that the calling function or a higher level object owns `obj2`, then you must not delete `obj2` when you delete `obj1`.

You asked:

> if I delete obj1.. obj2 and obj3 get deleted auotmatically. Why?

Because you did not write the code to delete them.

> Is this a memory leak?

Yes.

> Are they actually deleted?

No.

> I don't understand such behaviour. Shouldn't there be a delete for every new?

Yes. there should. However, you have to make sure that `delete` is called on each object returned from `new`.

If your policy is that `obj1` owns `obj2` after the above mentioned call, you have to implement the destructor of `A` to delete `next` and `previous`. However, you have to make sure that the links are properly taken care of before you do that. Otherwise, you will run into pointers that have already been deleted, you will run into memory leaks if you don't take care of traversing the links correctly.

```
~A()
{
   // Hopefully next->previous points to this.
   // You have to unlink next from this. Otherwise, 'delete next' will end up calling
   // delete on 'this`.
   // Similarly with previous

   if ( next != nullptr )
   {
       next->previous = nullptr;
      delete next;
   }

   if ( previous!= nullptr )
   {
       previous->next= nullptr;
      delete previous;
   }
}
```

You still have to call

```
delete obj1;
```

in `main` to make sure that all the objects are deleted.

If your policy is that the calling function or a higher level object owns `objt2` after the statement

```
obj1->setNext(obj2);
```

you have to call delete on all the objects from the calling function.

```
int main()
{
  A* obj1 = new A();
  A* obj2 = new A(); 
  A* obj3 = new A();

  obj1->setNext(obj2);
  obj2->setNext(obj3);
  obj3->setNext(nullptr);

  obj1->setPrevious(nullptr);
  obj2->setPrevious(obj1);
  obj3->setPrevious(obj2);

  delete obj3;
  delete obj2;
  delete obj1;

  return 0;
}
```

To make this a little cleaner, you should deal with a higher level container that is analogous to `std::list`. You add and remove items from the list. When the list is deleted, it has to make sure that all the contained elements are deleted too.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed reply. Yes there was confusion about ownership of instances but was able to fix it.